# How do I block results for particular words in my Google Custom Search Engine?

Tags: google-custom-search

I am aware of how to remove websites from search results in my Google Custom Search Engine *(either by using the control panel or uploading annotations in an xml file under 'advanced')... but how do I filter results for entire words? ( a.k.a. filtering results for search terms)?

For example, I want search results to come up blank for certain words that are not already Google's own safe search default.

Answer (score 1):

You can block specific search query terms using this method:

1. go to cse.google.com
2. under Setup tab, go to Sites to search
3. click Advanced
4. click Add
5. use your cse link to block the terms
6. click Exclude just the specifice pages that I have entered
7. click Save
   Example shown below:
   If I want to block the search term "hello," It would look like this:
   https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=(your_search_engine_ID)gsc.tab=0=hello

Answer (score -1):

I don't see a way to restrict by specific search terms, but you can force the results to be "Safesearch: Strict".

Under "Search Features" click the "Advanced" tab. Then under "Websearch Settings" click the radio button for Safesearch that you want: Off, Moderate, or Strict.

(In that same area you can also add extra query terms, but these are added to the user's query with an OR operator, so really it can only let you add extra results, not restrict them.)